# Informix error in Perl: ISAM: 107: ISAM error: record is locked. at test_db_connectivity.pl line 14

Tags: perl, informix

I'm trying to connect to our database in our production environment.  I am getting the **107 ISAM error:  record is locked** .  I have checked various articles on what it could be, but no luck.  I double checked the database details with our DBA and the information is correct.

FYI - Also the first error previous to the "record is locked" error I received was **SQL: -931: Cannot locate web1_tcp service/tcp service in /etc/services. at test_db_connectivity.pl line 13.** .  I worked with our SA to get that entered and that is no longer appearing.  Can anyone offer any guidance on the ISAM 107 error?  Is my connection string wrong?  There shouldn't be a lock because I am not even opening a connection to the database.

**test_db_connectivity.pl:**

```
#/usr/bin/perl -w

use DBI;
use strict;
use DBI qw(:sql_types);
use DBD::Informix qw(:ix_types);

    my $driver = "Informix";
    my $database = "web1";
    my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:dbname=$database";
    my $userid = "user";
    my $password = "password";
    print "I got this far!\n";
    my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password, {RaiseError => 1}) or      die $DBI::errstr;
    print "Opened db successfully\n";
    $dbh->disconnect();
```

**Some of the variables set:**

```
export INFORMIXDIR=/opt/informix

export   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$INFORMIXDIR/lib:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/cli:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/tools

export INFORMIXSERVER=web1
```

**INFORMIX SQLHOSTS FILE:**

#dbservername   nettype         hostname        servicename    options

web1           onsoctcp        10.199.***.*    web1dev1_tcp

**etc/services FILE:**

web1dev1_tcp  1533/tcp                # Port assigned to database

## virtual-places  1533/tcp                # Virtual Places Software

web1dev1_tcp  1533/udp                # Port assigned to database

Comment: This is on a VM host.  So this would be a remote connection.  Is there a different format to do such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, there is a system error 107:

```
107 (ENOTCONN): Transport endpoint is not connected
```

It is hard to distinguish that from a C-ISAM error 107 (the number is the same).  However, in context, I think the ENOTCONN is far more likely to be the problem than

```
ISAM ERROR 107: record is locked.
```

I observe that you're using a notation in `$dsn` that DBD::Informix doesn't test for:

```perl
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:dbname=$database";
```

The `dbname=` portion of that is incorrect.  You should use:

```
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:$database";
```

Note that the DBI spec (when I last looked) said that what follows the driver name is driver-specific.  You could submit an enhancement request.

However, on my working system, when I use the `dbname=stores` notation, the error I get is:

```
DBI connect('dbname=stores', '',...) failed: SQL: -354: Incorrect database or cursor name format. at dbname-dsn.pl line 8.
```

That's quite different.  You say you got:

> SQL: -931: Cannot locate web1_tcp service/tcp service in /etc/services. at test_db_connectivity.pl line 13

The error message is quite explicit.  You need an entry in `/etc/services` such as:

```
web1_tcp    9088/tcp
```

At the moment, you do not have such an entry, and therefore the connection is not even attempted, much less successful.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't vpn to my desktop for some reason will try this as soon as i can get back in.  Yes I worked with our SA to fix the /etc/services portion that error is gone.  Will try your suggestion when I can log back in.

Comment: Okay changed it to "my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:$database";" and it is still giving me the same error of "107 ISAM error: record is locked " when running the script on the Linux host as root.  The full error is:  "attempt to connect to database server (web1) failed 107 ISAM error: record is locked."

Comment: Do you also get the -931 error still?  Or has that changed?  The problem is probably still connectivity setup — unless you've had connections working to this database from this machine before (but if so, what settings did you use, and which software?).  To debug this, I'll need to see the relevant entry in the `sqlhosts` file (usually `$INFORMIXDIR/etc/sqlhosts`), and I'll need to understand which machines are involved, and where the client (Perl) software is running, and where the Informix server is running, and so on.  Did you build DBD::Informix on this machine?

Comment: Yes. I worked with the SA to fix the -931 error, previously to making this post on StackOverflow.  After the SA did it, I then ran my script and got the ISAM 107 error.  No, this is a new VM we are building out. Okay thanks I have posted the sqlhosts file and the etc/services file above.  And yes Perl is running on the current hosts sandbox-prod-supt.  Yes we built the DBD:Informix module on this same host.  This is the first time we have had any db connections setup on this machine. Not sure if the port could be the problem?

Comment: Thanks I had the wrong port listed in my etc/services file!  I got past that error.

Comment: That'll cause the trouble — well done on getting it fixed.